# HelloSign sendSignatureRequest($request) not working throw error

Tags: php, api, sdk, electronic-signature

I am new on HelloSign when i try to send signature request to hellos sign following error show..

```
       Fatal error: Uncaught HelloSign\Error: [file not found] 
     File does not exist. Please use an absolute file path. thrown in         
    C:\wamp\www\NewHelloSign\library\HelloSign\AbstractResource.php on line 216


        <?
        require_once('HelloSign\Client.php');

        require_once('HelloSign\BaseException.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\AbstractObject.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\AbstractList.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\Signer.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\SignerList.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\SignatureList.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\AbstractResource.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\Account.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\BaseException.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\Error.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\AbstractSignatureRequest.php');
        require_once('HelloSign\SignatureRequest.php');









        $client = new HelloSign\Client('MyID');
        $request = new HelloSign\SignatureRequest;
        $request->enableTestMode();
        $request->setSubject('HelloSign Twilio API Demo - Sign This');
        $request->setMessage('Check your phone for a secret pin to sign this document. We sent the pin to 1234567890 which should arrive shortly.');
        $request->addSigner(new HelloSign\Signer(array(
            'name' => 'jack',
            'email_address' => 'jack@example.com',
            'pin' => 'abcd1234'
        )));
        $request->addFile('http://localhost/NewHelloSign/library/omega-multi.pdf');
        $response = $client->sendSignatureRequest($request);
        print_r($response);
         ?>
```

$response not return any value.. where i am wrong please suggest me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$request->setSigner('Authorized Agent', '<email>', '<name>');
```